# Use linq to compute length of line defined as array of points

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of points:

```
 Point[] line; // { Point(1,1), Point(2,3), Point(1,1) }
```

Assuming Point has the relevant operators, what's the most linq-y way of computing the length of this line?

My best effort so far is:

```
float length = Enumerable.Range(0, line.Length-2)
    .Select(pointIndex => (line[pointIndex+1] - line[pointIndex]).Magnitude)
    .Sum();
```

Seems like there's a lot of subscripting in there though.

I would think there's a way to do something like this pseudocode:

```
float length = line.PairwiseMap(p1, p2 => (p2 - p1).Magnitude).Sum();
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possible answer (first time I've ever suggested two answers) is to keep your existing approach, but modified just a little bit by using `.Select()`'s under-appreciated little brother that gives you access to an index variable:

```
float length = line.Skip(1)
    .Select((point, index) => (point - line[index]).Magnitude)
    .Sum();
```

Heck, speaking of overloads.  You can also keep your existing approach but use `.Sum()`'s overload:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, line.Length - 1)
    .Sum(pointIndex => (line[pointIndex + 1] - line[pointIndex]).Magnitude)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use linq `Zip` instead of `PairwiseMap`. There is a drawback, you have to create two new enumerations with points:

```
//  collection of point/tuples
var points = new[] { 
    Tuple.Create(1f, 1f), 
    Tuple.Create(2f, 3f), 
    Tuple.Create(5f, 5f), 
    Tuple.Create(0f, 0f) 
};

// your implementation
Enumerable
    .Range(0, points.Length - 1)
    .Select(index => Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(points[index].Item1 - points[index + 1].Item1, 2) + Math.Pow(points[index].Item2 - points[index + 1].Item2, 2)))
    .Sum();

var left = points.Take(points.Length - 1); // starting points of verctors
var right = points.Skip(1); // ending points of verctors

// zip and calculate magnitude
left
     .Zip(right, (x, y) => 
         Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x.Item1 - y.Item1, 2f) + Math.Pow(x.Item2 - y.Item2, 2f)))
.Sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.Aggregate()` which is a way to fold an operation over a list with an accumulator

```
if (line.Any())
    length = line.Skip(1)
            .Aggregate(
                new { Point = line.First(), Length = 0d }, //seed
                (accum, point) => new { Point = point, Length = accum.Length + (point - accum.Point).Magnitude })
            .Length
else
    length = 0;
```

In this case, our accumulator is a `Tuple<Point, double>`, where the `double` is the length so far.

One advantage to this approach is that your points collection doesn't need to be an array or even have random access, just be an `IEnumerable<Point>`.  OTOH, `.Aggregate()` can be clunky, and you may prefer the readability of @akim's answer.

Comment: You're right, it's almost too slick. Very nice though!